# Как переименовать папку ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛИ в USERS?

Tags: windows-10

Срочно нужно переименовать папку ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛИ в USERS, везде копаюсь и везде про папку пользоватеЛЯ.

Comment: Встречный вопрос: как вы умудрились переименовать её в ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛИ? По умолчанию она расположена по адресу `C:\Users` и никаких русских букв в своём имени не имеет. Вы проверяли через командную строку командой `dir`, что она и в самом деле называется не Users?

Comment: У меня она изначально на русском, винда русская

Comment: Даже в русской винде она всегда называется `C:\Users` и я никогда не встречал её переименованную. Проверьте название папки через командную строку командой `dir`

Comment: Да, на английском

Comment: Вообще, в винде можно обращятся по пути C:\Users и по пути C:\Пользователи (русская локализация) (ОДНОВРЕМЕННО), это все транслируется на уровне путей автоматически. Единственное, древнючий Documents and Settings по факту есть, но заблокирован.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Она и так называется `Users`, просто Windows показывает по-другому.

Если заглянешь в файл `C:\Users\desktop.ini`, там есть

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21813
```

если это удалить, по идее будет показываться реальное имя.

Comment: Я удалил и когда сохраняю (заменяю) выходит что отсутствуют разрешение на открытие этого файла.

Comment: Всё помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Там манифест лежит в `c:\users\desktop.ini` , в котором написанно переводить эту папку. На самом деле она изначально называется users в windows 10.

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21813
```

Чтоб это отредактировать найди в поиске notepad, правой кнопкой,запусти от имени администратора.

Насколько помню documents and settings в более старых версиях было через символьную ссылку.